# Modify Map Service Symbology via Esri JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, tiles, arcgis-online, map-service

I have a JavaScript application built on the Esri JavaScript API that is consuming a feature service and a tiled map service from ArcGIS Online.  I developed a widget that allows the user to change the symbology of the feature service layer.  Is it possible to change the symbology of the tile map service once it has been published?  I didn't see a way to do that in the ArcGIS Online Web Map Viewer.

Comment: ask here: http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/15-ArcGIS-API-for-JavaScript

Comment: he can ask here too matt :)

Comment: @mapBaker - I am aware of the Esri forums, but my experience has been that SE is a much more active community where I am more likely to have my questions answered.  I have never had much luck finding answers on the Esri-specific forums.  Also, I tend to work with many different technologies and it's nice to have one resource where I can ask and answer questions related to many different technologies and that's what SE provides.

Comment: the JS API sub-forum specifically is lucky to have VERY active user and developer engagement, so please don't hesitate to use both resources anytime you have a question.

Comment: @Brian you're just taking the work away from good Esri Tech Support staff like John Gravois...and any time you're using paid software - why WOULDN'T you want the good support the company builds itself on...and...I'm getting a little ticked off by all the ArcGIS questions on here when there is a whole support forum built and maintained by the staff at ESRI - gis.stack is where the open source folks depend on getting support...its getting ArcClogged...

Comment: @Brian I was led to believe that changing symbology via JavaScript API isn't possible http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2396&t=300125 can you give me more info on how you acheived this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible to redefine the symbology of a tiled map service because the content has already been drawn and stored on the server to optimize client drawing performance.

Comment: Thanks John, that is exactly what I suspected, but it's always good to verify suspicions.